# MVC 5, EntityFramework 6 CF, Identity (authorization)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, identity, entity-framework-6

I decided to add authorization by means of Identity added in MVC 5.

In the project there was one context and use EF CodeFirst -

```
public class PostDBContext : DbContext
```

I added authorization with Identity EntityFramework use, but there the context -

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

As it will be more correct: to integrate my old context with a context used for authorization, thereby to change a class from which it is inherited and to transfer everything to one?

Or to leave two contexts?

And what change of my context with DbContext on IdentityDbContext will entail?
I use one database.
I checked and both options work. Whether will be then difficulties?
Thanks!

Comment: What version of EntityFramework are you using? for me I updated my application to EF 6.0.2 and when I inherit my dbcontext from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, it starts complaining in global.asax's database initialization

Comment: I use EntityFramework 6.0.2

Comment: file IdentityConfig.cs to change on - public class MyDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using 1 context, I created a MVC 5 application a few weeks ago, and was wondering the same thing, but it is so easy to just use 1 context. And why not? Everything used to access it should be independent of it...

My tip, use 1 context :)..

Comment: DbContext or IdentityDbContext? If I only use you should my codefirst entities inherit from IdentityDbConext too?

Comment: I would use a single Context class inheriting from IdentityDbContext. This way you can have the context be aware of any relations between your classes and the IdentityUser and Roles of the IdentityDbContext.